# How to mock functions on import of main module?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following problem:

My `main.py` contains:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager    

secret_name = "abc"

def function_1(secret):
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    name = f"projects/123/secrets/{secret}/versions/latest"
    response = client.access_secret_version(name=name)
    return response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

def function_2():
    secret = function_1(secret_name)
    return secret

secret = function_2()
```

and my `test_main.py` has:

```
def test_function_1():
    import main
    ...
```

When running this and other tests in `test_main.py` I get an error because by importing main `function_2` is called and e.g. the access_secret_version method is called unmocked. I don't want to change my `main.py` and for example put `secret = function_2()` under `if __name__=="__main__"`. I want to fix this in `test_main.py`.

I tried different things like

```
@patch('main.secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient')
@patch('main.secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient.access_secret_version')
def test_function_1():
    import main
    ...
```

but `import main` is always calling these methods unmocked. How can I do this? How can I mock what `function_2` is calling?

Here [Mock function called on import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616934/mock-function-called-on-import) the OP found a similar workaround.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Putting that code unter under `if __name__ == "__main__"` is actually the correct way to do this and the accepted practice in Python - anything else would just be a workaround. Is there a reason why you don't want to use it?

Comment: I have a flask app in `main.py` and I want `secret = function_2()` to be a global variable that is available when starting the app. I tried to find out how to call the function before/after `app.run` for that but could not successfully make it work so that `secret` is assigned before referenced in other functions so I thought fixing the problem in the unit test is easier.

Comment: You already have a solution, but generally you could have used a function instead of a global variable (that also could initialize a global variable lazily if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module in the `@patch` decorator should be `google.cloud` instead of `main`, otherwise you're importing from main in order to patch (which runs `function_2` before it's patched).

```
@patch('google.cloud.secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient')
```

Comment: That's not correct - it would not patch the needed object, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen When you `import main` within the test function, doesn't it look up the patched function from 
 `google.cloud.secretmanager` for the first time?

Comment: It works on my test script: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ceneqiduje

Comment: It works with `request` as this is a module. It does indeed look up `google.cloud.secretmanager` at first load, and creates a local reference to `secretmanager`, which will not be mocked, if you mock `google.cloud.secretmanager` instead of `main.secretmanager`.

Comment: "It works with request as this is a module." ... and `google.cloud.secretmanager` is also a module.

Comment: Just tested with the actual code, works for me. https://paste.pythondiscord.com/gehovozuzi

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you very much it worked. I didn't think about it but I'm also calling `requests.post`  in function_2 which I'm importing with `import requests`. How does the patch look like here? I tried `@patch('requests')` but no success.

Comment: I take it all back - I wasn't aware that `secretmanager` is a separate module - in this case it will work. As for `requests` - you should probably patch `requests.post`.